# JQuery keyup event is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, keyup

I use Jquery keyup event to listen input event , But some of my application users can not work;

Here my situation is： I use JQuery keyup event to listen input event; but some users under window XP IE7 or IE 8(chrome or fire fox works well mostly), The keyup event  just can not fire, some of them reboot the system, and find it can work,but others can not;

my JS code:

```
    this.$discountInput.on('keyup', function(e){
        self.__keyevent_handle(e, self);
    });

    this.$reducedInput.on('keyup', function(e){
        self.__keyevent_handle(e, self);
    });

    this.$preferentialInput.on('keyup', function(e){
        self.__keyevent_handle(e, self);
    });
```

I debugged the code; the function of __keyevent_handle is not always execute because of the keyup event can not be fired;

Some of my mates suggest use the "input propertychange", but I am not sure;
also can "paste keyup input change" bind work??

any answer will be appreciated,
thank you!!!

Comment: Could it be that `self` is giving you trouble? I assume `__keyevent_handle` is a globally accessible function (attached to the `window` object), in that case you can leave the `self.` off.

Comment: try to use `onkeyup` attribute of your `<input>` in addition to the functions you have written.

Comment: @MDeSchaepmeester self is not the problem,because I have debugg the code; I write a very simple JQuery keyup event code run on my app users computer; and the event can't work; what confused me is :WHY some of them just reboot the system and things go well

Comment: @Nikhil Talreja Sorry but do what???? Then his function would be executed twice.

Comment: What jQuery version are you using? Note that the 2.x branch will no longer support IE7 and 8.

Comment: jQuery version: jQuery v1.10.2

Comment: @Windkiller The function is called only once even if its bound using `onkeyup` and `jQuery`. [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WYwLK/) here.

Comment: Be on the lookout for plugins. They can muck up key events. Also, if there is something cancelling keydowns you wont get a keyup.

Comment: @Nikhil Talreja O.o didnt know that. Thank you!